# Unable to obtain text box value (html) in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

```
<form name="myForm" action="MyServlet" method="POST">
     Please enter your search query here:<br>
     <input type="search" name="searchText" id="searchText" size="100" autocomplete="on" />
     <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
     <textarea cols="30" rows="10">Result will be displayed here</textarea>
     <a href="newhtml1.html">Click here</a> if result not displayed for your search query.
</form>
```

In my servlet

```
arg = request.getParameter("searchText");
      out.println(arg);
```

But I am getting the output as null.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<input type="text" name="searchText" .../>
```

Comment: No, `search` is a [perfectly acceptable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#text-(type=text)-state-and-search-state-(type=search)) input type (and if a browser doesn't recognise it then it would fallback to text by default)

Answer (score 0):

The search type is used for search fields (a search field behaves like a regular text field).
please refer this link http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1297854 better you can change the name of the id and try or remove it and try